# How to fix Sass Error: Invalid parent selector "[type=button]"

Tags: sass

I switched my Sass compiler from libsass/sassc 3.6.2 to Dart Sass 1.44.0 and now I get this error. I have no idea what that means. Is it a bug?

```
Error: Invalid parent selector "[type=button]"
    ╷
312 │ ┌     &a:link,
313 │ │     &a:visited
314 │ │     {
    │ └────^
    ╵
```

This is the code:

```
#{$buttonInputs},
div.buttons a,
span.buttons a,
a.button
{
    // (some lines omitted...)
    &a:link,
    &a:visited
    {
        color: $buttonColor;
        text-decoration: none !important;
    }
}
```

And this definition in an imported file:

```
$buttonInputs: "button, input[type=button], input[type=color], input[type=image], input[type=reset], input[type=submit]";
```

Why is there a difference between both Sass compilers? And how do I get rid of the error to continue my work?

Comment: I don't understand your code. How could `input[type=button]a` be a valid selector ? Is it an `a` or an input ? It can't be both.

Comment: The first level covers some `input`s as well as `a`, so it clearly could match.

Comment: @AmauryHanser your comment just solved my issue.  Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

@AmauryHanser had a good point in the comments on the initial question.

For every type listed in the enclosing selector, and every use of the `&` in the nested selector, the compiler is going to combine them (exactly as written, no added spaces).  Notice how things like `button` from the enclosing selector list and `a` from the nested selector become mashed together into a single element `buttona` because there was no space between `&` and `a:link` in the nested selector:

```
//compiler output

buttona:link, buttona:visited {
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

input[type=button]a:link, input[type=button]a:visited {...omitted for brevity...} 

input[type=color]a:link, input[type=color]a:visited {...}

input[type=image]a:link, input[type=image]a:visited {...}

input[type=reset]a:link, input[type=reset]a:visited {...} 

input[type=submit]a:link, input[type=submit]a:visited {...}

div.buttons aa:link,div.buttons aa:visited {...}

span.buttons aa:link,span.buttons aa:visited {...}

a.buttona:link, a.buttona:visited {...}
```

It's possible your previous compiler was processing the & operator more intelligently, or just didn't care to report errors on the non-sensical rules that were being produced.

I would recommend:
a) Removing `a` from your nested selector rules so the `:linked` and `:visited` pseudo-classes apply directly on whatever is coming from the enclosing selector

```
#{$buttonInputs},
div.buttons a,
span.buttons a,
a.button
{
    
    &:link, // a removed
    &:visited
    {
        color: $buttonColor;
        text-decoration: none !important;
    }
}
```

or
b) Putting a space between `&` and `a` so `a:visited` and `a:link` are treated as DOM descendants of whatever the enclosing selector is.

```
#{$buttonInputs},
div.buttons a,
span.buttons a,
a.button
{
    & a:link, // space added
    & a:visited
    {
        color: $buttonColor;
        text-decoration: none !important;
    }
}
```

but I would also say that the list of elements coming from the enclosing selector rule is not suitable for the nested selector rule, since `a` doesn't make sense as a child of `input` nor does `:visited` make sense as a pseudo-class of `input`.

Comment: I've removed the extra "a" long ago now (an extra space would be wrong here), but this is a good explanation of what's going on. String concatenating explains how this is nonsense. IIRC, my previous compiler interpreted this `&a` as "`&` only if it's an `a` from previous selectors", i.e. it doesn't apply to the non-`a` variants like `input`. Seems like this feature has been removed from Sass.